# Does amazon s3 have a limit to the number of subfolders you create?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am thinking of using amazon s3 to implement my own backup solution. The idea is to have have a script that accepts a directory and recursively uploads all files underneath that directory into s3. However, I am not sure if it would work because of the following reasons.

- s3 apparently doesn't have folders.
- s3 imposes a limit on the size of the name of objects (1024 characters).

I take this to mean that if an object identified as "/foo/bar/baz.txt", then the "/foo/bar/" portion of that "filepath" is actually part of the object's name and counts towards the character limit on object names. If this is true, then I could see this becoming an issue when uploading deeply nested files with long filepaths (although 1024 characters does seem fairly generous).

Am I understanding things correctly?

Comment: Though I've answered this, I shouldn't have done really, as it's not about programming and thus off-topic. Ideally it would get migrated to SuperUser or somesuch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, this is accurate.**

S3 is a key/value store, not a filesystem, though backups are certainly somethings its authors expect it to be used for (as evidenced by the documentation's choice of example keys being mostly filepaths!). If your computer has directory structures and filenames so long and so deeply nested that their entire path exceeds a *thousand* characters, I'd strongly recommend reorganising your hard drive!

If you can't do that and have lots of long paths, you may wish to try something other than attempting a one-to-one mapping between the two things. For example, you could store data blobs (the content of a file) with a key that is some GUID. Have a separate key/value store that maps GUIDs to filepaths. Although that doesn't help you with reverse lookup. Basically do the same thing you'd do if you were trying to structure this efficiently in code, using algorithms and data structures. Because, really, that's what you're doing here, too!

Putting backups aside and speaking more generally, if you were using subdirectories on disk only as a sort of metadata, there are other metadata properties you can use in S3 for that. But your object keys would still have to be unique across the whole dataset.

You can read [more about S3 objects in the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingObjects.html).

Comment: Further to this idea, if the backup software intends to keep multiple versions of a file (eg if a file was changed, should it keep the previous version?), this breaks the 1:1 match of source filename to destination filename and adds more reason for using a data blog with a GUID.

Comment: A very good point, though S3 does have a version ID for each object.